# Single specific string replace method Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, string

I wanted to know if theres a single method or way that will help me replace strings for specific characters.

like MALE - M
FEMALE - F
CHILD  - P

The longer way out is this..

```
[str stringByreplacingOccurencesOfString:@"MALE" withString:@"M"];
[str stringByreplacingOccurencesOfString:@"FEMALE" withString:@"F"];
[str stringByreplacingOccurencesOfString:@"CHILD" withString:@"P"];
```

I was wondering if theres another way in which i can reduce lines of code here, specially when there are alots of things to replace.

thanks.

this is for iPhone OS.

Answer (score 2):

No, but it shouldn't take more than 5-10 minutes to write a method that takes an array or varargs to do it for you.

Comment: using an array?? any simple example?

Comment: I've loaded all strings "to be replaced" in an NSDictionary. And I kept doing, [str stringByReplacingOc..@"MALE" withString:[dict objectForKey:@"MALE"]];

There are sooo many replacements, any detail is appreciated man.

Comment: I had an idea, where i'd attach '$' in the beginning of the str to be replaced. for example.
$Male is for M 

What Maybe I could do is, look for the $ character and then take that word out and replace it from the Dictionary. Maybe its easier than looping through a long list?

I wish I new how to do that..